# A queue of Promises inside a Promise

Tags: javascript

I'm inside some Promise, in `then` case, where I have some array and I need to call a queue of async functions with the next 100 items of the array as a parameter (length is unknown).

```
uri = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, ...];

somePromiseFunction()
  .then((resp) => function2(resp.id, uri));
```

function2 can get 100 items in one time, after it finished it can take next 100 etc.

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to show use what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to say from such fragmentary information, but...

### If you want to call them in parallel...

...use `map` and `Promise.all`:

```
.then(() => Promise.all(theArray.slice(0, 100).map(item => theAsyncFunction(item))))
```

Note that `slice` is okay with it if the ending index is beyond the end of the array.

If `theAsyncFunction` only uses its first argument and ignores any others you pass it, you can pass it directly to `map` instead of using an arrow function:

```
.then(() => Promise.all(theArray.slice(0, 100).map(theAsyncFunction)))
```

If you want to **remove** the entries from the array at the same time, you can use `splice` instead of `slice`

```
.then(() => Promise.all(theArray.splice(0, 100).map(theAsyncFunction)))
```

`splice` will remove the entries from the original array (modifying it) and return an array of those entries.

### If you want to run them in series...

...use the "promise reduce trick":

```
.then(() =>
    theArray.slice(0, 100).reduce((p, item) =>
        p.then(() => theAsyncFunction(item)),
        Promise.resolve()
    )
)
```

...again using `splice` if you want to remove them.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I can't call them in parallel.

Comment: @Laudinio - I've added a series option.

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use `async/await`. It should simplifies your code execution.

```
`let asyncFuntion = async function(data){
// do stuff
}

let sampleArray = []  // assume it has 100 elements
let execArray = []

 for(let elem of sampleArray){
    execArray.push(asyncFuntion(elem))
 }

 let resultArray = await Promise.all(execArray) // it would executed all  the 100 elements in async way

 // you have all 100 element's results in this resultArray`
```